# How can I check if certain elements are in a code in python

Tags: python

This is what I mean, lets say I'm working with checking to which telephone operator does a certain telephone number belong to

```
tel = input("Enter telephone number: ")

# Say I want to check if 077, #0782, 0783, 070 are in the user input
# Say the telephone numbers [0782123123, 078312312, 07712312] 
# which belong to Operator1 are entered by the user 
# I want be able to sort out the user's input 

if 0783, 077, 070,0782 are in tel: 
  Then print ("This number belongs to Operator 1")

and if 0755, 0723 are in tel:
   Then print ("This number belongs to Operator 2")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to specify the expected input and output *as valid Python code*? It is currently not clear what ``0782, 0783, 070`` and such are (are they numbers, strings, a single string?). See the [mcve] page how to best present partial programs.

Comment: 0783, 077, 070,0782  all must be there in input or anyone? to print "This number belongs to Operator 1" ?

Comment: Please provide clear information about your problem and what you are trying to output

Comment: Do you mean that the phone number should start with one of those numbers, or just contain one of them?

Comment: Oh yes Khelwood

Comment: Why do you want to "check if 077, #0782, 0783, 070 are in the user input" when you know "the telephone numbers [ 0782123123, 078312312, 07712312] which belong to Operator1"? Why not just check whether the input equals any of [0782123123, 078312312, 07712312]?

Comment: I asked an either/or question. "Oh yes" isn't really a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in function [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
tel = input("Enter telephone number: ")

if any(num in tel for num in ('0783', '077', '070','0782')):
  print ("This number belongs to Operator 1")

if any(num in tel for num in ('0755', '0723')):
   print ("This number belongs to Operator 2")
```

Comment: @BlackElephant feel free to upvote and mark as accepted :)

Comment: Up and the green tick which is which

Comment: @BlackElephant The green tick is accepting the answer (only 1 answer can be accepted per question and only by the person asking the question) and the up arrow marks the answer as useful (multiple answers can be marked useful by anyone).

Answer (score 0):

```
tel = input("Enter telephone number: ")
check1 = ["0783", "077", "070", "0782"]
check2 = ["0755", "0723"]
if any(x in tel for x in check1):
    print("This number belongs to Operator 1")
elif any(x in tel for x in check2):
    print("This number belongs to Operator 2")
else:
    print("This number neither belongs to Operator 1 nor to 
                operator 2")
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: `check2` is never used here. If someone typed 'abcd' this would output `This number belongs to Operator 2`

Comment: big_bad_bison you are right using check2 will output This number belongs to Operator 2

Comment: I didn't include the elif statement, now I think it's good to go and thank you big_bad_bison for reminding me the mistake.